# PySide2 raises error, "QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted"

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to paint something on a `QPixmap`, but it throws an error during cleanup.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication()
width = 200
height = 100
pixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
painter = QPainter(pixmap)
painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
print('Done.')
```

When I run that, I see the 'Done' message, and then an error.

```
Done.
QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I've seen some similar questions with the same error, but it's not clear what's causing the error or how to avoid it.

Answer (score 9):

After experimenting, it seems that the `painter` has to clean up before the `pixmap` does, otherwise you get the error. For example, this works without error.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication()
width = 200
height = 100
pixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
painter = QPainter(pixmap)
painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
print('Done.')

del painter
del pixmap
```

You can also tell the `painter` to clean up without destroying it. Just tell it that you've finished painting by calling `end()`.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication()
width = 200
height = 100
pixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
painter = QPainter(pixmap)
painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
print('Done.')

painter.end()
```

There are some other things that avoid the error for mysterious reasons. For example, this avoids the error.

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication()
width = 200
height = 100
pixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
painter = QPainter(pixmap)
painter.device()  # <-- No idea why this helps!
painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
print('Done.')
```

In summary, just make sure that the painter cleans up before the pixmap does. I would recommend either using the painter in a smaller scope than the pixmap or explicitly calling `painter.end()`.